# I want to read content of 10 different website and save them into 10 diferrent text files

Tags: c#

I have been able to read the content of a web page and saved it into a file. This question is, how do I read for 10 different webpages without having to repeat the code over and over again. Is there a loop mechanism that can help? Here is what I have done:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
   Task Task1 = new Task(() => ReadWriteWeb("http://www.hawaii.edu"));
   Task1.Start();
   Console.ReadLine();
}
static void ReadWriteWeb(string Url)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient WebC = new WebClient())
        {
            string WebContents = WebC.DownloadString(Url);
            Console.WriteLine(WebContents);
                using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter("myFile")
                    SW.WriteLine(WebContents + ".  " + "The lenght of file  is {0}", WebContents.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The web content cannot be reached");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you typed `C# loop` into a search engine such as Google yet?

Comment: I don't know why you received -3 votes already.  I don't see anything wrong with your question, even if some consider it simple it's still a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me, but assuming you are aware of loops already as I hope you are here is an the answer I thought you would be looking for.  This will download all the files simultaneously via a simple loop / multithreaded feature of linq.

```
public class Program
{
    volatile static int fileNameCounter = 1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfTasks = new List<Task>()
        {
            new Task(() => ReadWriteWeb("http://www.hawaii.edu")),
            new Task(() => ReadWriteWeb("http://www.hawaii.edu")),
            new Task(() => ReadWriteWeb("http://www.hawaii.edu")),
            new Task(() => ReadWriteWeb("http://www.hawaii.edu"))
        };

        listOfTasks.AsParallel().ForAll(task => task.Start());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async void ReadWriteWeb(string Url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File {fileNameCounter} complete");

        try
        {
            using (WebClient WebC = new WebClient())
            {
                string WebContents = await WebC.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Url);
                Console.WriteLine(WebContents);
                using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter($"myFile{fileNameCounter++}"))
                    SW.WriteLine(WebContents + ".  " + "The lenght of file  is {0}", WebContents.Length);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The web content cannot be reached");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Since I only had the one web url I listed the same one 4 times. You get the idea...

Comment: Thank you Michael Puckett. I perfectly understand the idea. It worked as expected. Before now, i am ignorant of the multithreaded feature of linq. Thank you for the enlightenment. if you could kindly point me to a link where i can read more about this feature, i will be more than grateful.

Comment: Linq has a plethora of flexibility and options.  Here's the best link-2-linq (pun intended) I can offer.  From there just dig as needed. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I just noticed that link doesn't have an explanation of example of AsParallel.  I'll do my best to explain it.  When you have a query of multiple objects you can choose .AsParallel() which will return a ParallelQuery<TSource> object.  The ParallelQuery object basically runs any work on the enumeration simultaneously.  The extension method ForAll() just allows you to pass an action to each item in the enumeration and since it's on AsParellel it happens on tasks at the same time.

Comment: You could put listOfTasks.ForEach(task => task.Start()); and this would perform the task.Start() actions one at a time.  Since it is a task and there is no await you will get a similar result.  Keep in mind that you could be awaiting or you may be calling methods that aren't tasks and then they would iterate one after the other using ForEach as opposed to AsParallel.ForAll which would still perform the work simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Standard looping constructs in C# include the [for loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) and the [foreach loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx).

In general, anything you could **possibly** want to know about C# can be found in the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx) on MSDN.